# Есть ли утилита для проверки совместимости Pc железа с Mac os?

Tags: macos, mac, поиск-программ

Заинтересовался в установке os x на ноутбук. Не знаю нужно ли мне это, но хотелось бы знать поддерживает ли ос ноут или не париться и  сидеть на линуксе .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень много проблем может быть связано с установкой OS X на ноутбук. Если стационарный компьютер можно собрать с практически идентичными характеристиками к Mac и с полпинка завести OS X, то с ноутбуками намного сложнее. Даже если практически все характеристики идентичные. Главная проблема - в конфигурациях с переключаемой графикой (Intel+nVidia или Intel+AMD) в OS X работает только Intel. Подходят только видеокарты Intel HD3xxx,4ххх,5ххх.

Пример из жизни. Сотрудник ставил на свой ноутбук OS X, который схож с MacBook 15" по характеристикам - все прошло нормально, но как ни старался, клавиатура так и не заработала. А с внешней USB клавиатурой, ясное дело, это не то.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется "Хакинтош". Официально эпплом не поддерживается. Возможно нарушает лицензионное соглашение. Так что можно предложить только попробовать установить - заработает или нет.

Answer (score 0):

В AppStore заходишь со своим ID и переходишь в загрузки MacOs по идее он не даст тебе скачать MacOS, если железо не подойдёт ссылки просто будут неактивными, а ниже будут отображаться OS скорее всего очень древние, на подобие Lion 10.07, или Mountain Lion 10.8 конца 90-х начала 00-х ... смысла не будет от них

Comment: всё там даёт скачать, если конечно не очень древний ноут. но вайфай запускается только с со сторонним менеджером сети, а клавиатура в большинстве случаев не запускается вообще.